# Trying to connect Drools with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, drools

I am using Drools from my project and I'm trying to connect the knowledge base to Hibernate in order to extract the facts from Database .. However I couldn't quite figure out how : 
Should I create a hibernate session when creating the Knowledgebase ? or within the DRL files ? 
Could you help me please how to connect hibernate with drools ? 
thank you

Comment: It doesn't make sense to connect a `Drools knowledge base` to `Hibernate`. A KnowledgeBase is a static compilation of rules and the trimmings - so you don't have to hibernate that.

Comment: what I mean is I'm trying to extract the facts from hibernate .. 
From what I saw , objects are created into the knowledge base then drools makes the tests , what I want is testing the rules on facts from the databese , in order to do that , I need to connect drools to hibernate . 
Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Facts result from Java objects inserted into a Knowledge Session (aka Working Memory), which is created from a Knowledge Base. How you obtain these Java objects is up to you. If they should come from a DB, you must fetch them.

Comment: yes exactly thank you , in order to fetch them I am asking if you have an idea on how to connect drools with hibernate which will allow me to fetch them

Comment: As I tried to indicate: you do this by Java code you'll have to write.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i have understood your requirement properly. Still for someone this can help.
I Hope we can cover the DB interaction features via custom methods drived over global objects.

---

1. Imports a global class veriable into rules.
   global job.ExecuteTask globalHandler
2. Assume ExecuteTask Class has a variable to DAO Facade handler or Session Factory of Hibernate.
   public ManagerFacade ManagerFacade;
3. Set the global handler along with Kie session initialization.
   ksession.setGlobal("globalHandler", new ExecuteTask(jobReader, ksession, managerFacade));
4. On certain conditions/rules make calls to this initialized global handler's methods from rules.
   globalHandler.createPersistentObjectProd(Object args...);

This is kind of flowing back and forth from rules to backed custom methods.